# Macbook Pro 2020 M1 - MacOS Big Sur - Homebrew not working

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

Macbook Pro 2020 M1 - Big Sur

I have just updated gems (`gem update`) on ruby 2.6 (System ruby version default belong to OSX Big Sur, i think so)

(My global ruby using rbenv is 2.7.2, i installed it some days ago)

Now when i run any command such as `brew xxx` (brew doctor, brew config, brew upgrade, brew update ...)
It give me an error like as attached image.

Please can anyone help me, thanks so much!!!

[image]

Comment: A lot of compilers haven't caught up to Apple Silicon yet. That's part of why you're getting an arch error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary i resolved my issue by uninstall all incompatible ruby gems :
**date**, **etc**, **io-console**, **bigdecimal**

If you care, you can refer this discussion.
https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/716

Answer (score 0):

MacOs has released his latest software update for macos Big sur 11.2 try updating your software

And if it doesn't work them approach
https://discussions.apple.com

Comment: I just updated to 11.2 but still get error! :(